# nginx location regex - character class and range of matches

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

I am trying to setup a regex for the path `/s/<4-6 character string here>` where I capture the 4-6 character string as $1.

I tried using the following two entries, but both fail

```
location ~ ^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]){4,6}+$ { ...

location ~ ^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,6})+$ { ...
```

The first one comes up with 'unknown directive' and the second comes up with 'pcre_compile() failed: missing )'

**EDIT**

The following routes would be served by this location:

```
/s/1234 (and I would capture '1234' in $1)
/s/12345 (and I would capture '12345' in $1)
/s/123456 (and I would capture '123456' in $1)
/s/abcd (and I would capture 'abcd' in $1)
/s/abcde (and I would capture 'abcde' in $1)
/s/abcdef (and I would capture 'abcdef' in $1)
/s/a1b2c (and I would capture 'a1b2c' in $1)
```

The following routes would NOT be served by this location:

```
/s/1
/s/12
/s/123
/s/a
/s/ab
/s/abc
/s/abc1234
/s/12345678
```

etc...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to capture 4 to 6 characters, why you don't have put the quantifier inside the capture parenthesis?

Something like that perhaps:

```
location ~ "^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,6})$" {...
```

Curly braces are used both in regex and for block control, you must enclose your regex with quotes (single or double) (<-- wiki nginx)

Comment: I want to both capture and limit the string to be 4-6 characters.  You've got an unlimited # of characters after the first 4-6 with the '.*'

Comment: @Dave: Your request isn't clear. Please give a concrete example of url you want to treat.

Comment: I think my request is pretty clear.  I want to capture '1234' from '/s/1234' or 'abcde' from '/s/abcde' and NOT allow anything following '/s/' besides a 4, 5 or 6 character string.  So '/s/x' or '/s/xy' or '/s/xyz' or '/s/abcdxyz' would all not be served by this location block.

Comment: @Dave: If the path end after the 4-6 characters, just remove the .*

Comment: 'unknown directive "4,6}$' returned for ^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]){4,6}$ and 'pcre_compile() failed: missing ) in "^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]' for ^/s/([0-9a-zA-Z]{4,6})$

Comment: Ok! it's cause the curly braces. you must enclose your regex between quotes "

Comment: Thank you for the info that curly braces must be enclosed in quotes, that was killing me.

Comment: Did you resolve that? Could you please share the rule? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, put regex into quotes help me to fix quantifier issue.

Comment: Please help, my regex is below

`bill/([0-9a-zA-Z]{8})-([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})-([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})-([0-9a-zA-Z]{4})-([0-9a-zA-Z]{12})/download`



`nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "8}")-([0-9a-zA-Z]" in /etc/nginx'`